# Convert JSON objects into"value" "value" pairs

Tags: json

I have a JSON object with this structure:

[image]

I am trying to get it into this format

```
        {"123" : "Asthma", "124" : "Bronchitis".....}
```

I am pretty green with javascript and working with JSON. Some assistance would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var arr = [{id: 1, name: 'a'},{id: 2, name: 'b'},{id: 3, name: 'c'}];
var obj = {};

for (var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; ++i) {
    obj[arr[i].id] = arr[i].name;
}

console.log(obj);
```